# Solving an equation containing Laplace transform

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, fourier-transform, integral-transforms, laplace-transform

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(p)}{f(s_{1})}\mathcal{L}(y)(s_{1})+\frac{g(p)}{g(s_{2})}\mathcal{L}%
(y)(s_{2})=\mathcal{L(}y)\mathbf{(}p),
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Laplace transform of $y$ which we assume well
defined and $f,g$ are two functions such that
\begin{equation*}
f(p)=0\text{ }\Longleftrightarrow p=s_{2},\text{    }g(p)=0\text{ }%
\Longleftrightarrow p=s_{1}.
\end{equation*}
I want to prove that such a function $y$ exists if and only if $p=s_{1}$ or $%
p=s_{2}.$ The sufficient part is clear; for $p=s_{1}$ we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{f(s_{1})}{f(s_{1})}\mathcal{L}(y)(s_{1})+0 &=&\mathcal{L(}y)\mathbf{(}%
s_{1}), \\
&\Longrightarrow &\mathcal{L}(y)(s_{1})=\mathcal{L}(y)(s_{1}).
\end{eqnarray*}

The same thing holds for $p=s_{2}.$ I want to prove that a solution $y$
exists if and only if $p=s_{1}$ or $p=s_{2}.$ The sufficient part is clear,
but I cannot prove the necessary part. Any ideas?. Thank you.